# Apache RewriteRule with Querystring

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I've got a rewrite like this:

```
RewriteRule /products.php?id=123&t=12345 /product/New-Product-Name
```

If I turn on `RewriteLog`ging, and turn the level up, I get the following:

```
applying pattern '/products.php?id=123&t=12345' to uri '/products.php'
```

Why is the full uri (including querystring) not being looked at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `mod_rewrite` docs:

> Note: Query String
>
> The *Pattern* will not be matched against the query string. Instead, you must use a `RewriteCond` with the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string, containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string, to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark. To combine a new query string with an old one, use the `[QSA]` flag.

In short, you'll need to use a combination of `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`; maybe something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=123&t=12345$
RewriteRule /products.php /product/New-Product-Name
```

*Update*: I tested this, and it works as I described. It redirects to
`/product/New-Product-Name?id=123&t=12345`.

If you want the query string `?id=123&t=12345` to be removed, add a `?` to the `RewriteRule`, like:

```
RewriteRule /products.php /product/New-Product-Name?
```

which will redirect to
`/product/New-Product-Name`

I'm imagining there's a better way to do this using `RewriteMap`, but this might do for a one-off.